# "Unknown host machine name" with FreeTDS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, freetds

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS xential 32bit.
Currently I am trying to connect MSSQL Server Express 2019 running on the Windows10.
Got freeTDS and Unixodbc

I hit the command

```
tsql -S ipaddress -U username -P password
```

then,return

```
    Error 20012 (severity 2):
    Server name not found in configuration files.
    locale is "ja_JP.UTF-8"
    locale charset is "UTF-8"
    using default charset "UTF-8"
    Error 20013 (severity 2):
    Unknown host machine name.
    There was a problem connecting to the server
```

my odbc.ini is

```
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = xxxxx
ServerName              = ipadress
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

odbcinst.ini is

```
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

freetds.ini is

```
[egServer70]
    host = ipadress
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

does anybody help me what is wrong my setting files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `-H ipaddress` instead of `-S ipaddress`

Comment: Hi Gord, thanks for your suggestion. I will try after back to my home and let you know the results.

Comment: user# tsql -H 192.168.xx.xx -U username -P password
tsql: no default port provided by host 192.168.xx.xx
Missing argument -p, looking for default instance ... user:~# tsql -H 192.168.xx.xx -p 1433 -U user locale is "ja_JP.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"  still not connected to my mssql

Comment: SQLEXPRESS instances almost never listen on port 1433. You can use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to find out what port your instance is listening on. While you're in there, also verify that TCP/IP connections are enabled.

Comment: Hi Gord,
 I work with lots of SQLEXPRESS on windows servers and laptops. Usually I never changed the default port 1433 to else in past experience. 
In this time also TCP/IP is enabled in configureation manager. Also in the windows firewall property, the TCP 1433 port is opened. I will check if I can connect to my SQL server express from local.(using command line in the PC that SQL server Express running).  By the way, I guess if it is correct the version written in tdsodbc.ini and odbc.ini is not same? If you have anything other suggestion, please help me. Many thanks.